# How to get different time difference using moment?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I need to get the duration between two dates in `hh:mm:ss` format using moment. but i am not able to get the exact difference.  Here is my example.

```
let start = moment("2018-07-27T14:56:33.763Z");
let end = moment("2018-07-28T14:56:33.763Z");
let diff = end.diff(start);

let f = moment.utc(diff).format("HH:mm:ss");
alert(f);
```

For the above dates i need to get the output as `24:00:00`, because it's one day difference. But i am getting `00:00:00` as response.

If i am changing the hrs it should display based on that. how can i achieve this? can someone help me to fix this.

Comment: You need to get the number of days as well, since it's 1 day, 0 hours etc..

Comment: This isn't realted to Angular but moment, I'm editing your tags

Comment: Please check out my answer, you may want to consider downloading the plugin for this issue on Moments Website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a rather lengthy discussion on [Moments GitHub Page](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1048) but this may be what you are after:

```js
let start = moment("2018-07-27T14:56:33.763Z");
let end = moment("2018-07-28T14:56:33.763Z");
let duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
let f = Math.floor(duration.asHours()) + moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format(":mm:ss")

alert(f);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

By the way there is a [plugin](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format/) that someone created for this specific issue, which is posted on [Moments Website](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`let f = moment.utc(diff).format('D[days] H[ hours]');`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/98660/)

If you want to convert that time in only `HH:mm:ss` maybe you can manually convert it to miliseconds and parse it to hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to achieve the quest.

```js
let start = moment("2018-07-27T14:56:33.763Z");
let end = moment("2018-07-28T14:56:33.763Z");
let diff = end.diff(start);

var d = moment.duration(diff, 'milliseconds');
var hours = Math.floor(d.asHours());
var mins = Math.floor(d.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;
var secs = Math.floor(d.asSeconds()) - mins * 60 - hours * 60*60;;
console.log(  hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It states

```
enter code here
H, HH       24 hour time
h, or hh    12 hour time (use in conjunction with a or A)
```

Thus, stating your time as HH will give you 24h format, and hh will give 12h format.

Answer (score 0):

Since the difference is a day so hours,minutes,seconds return zero so change the condition in this way

```
let f = moment.utc(diff).format("HH:mm:ss");
if(f=="00:00:00"){
f=moment.utc(diff).format("D[days] H[hours]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is trying to format a difference of 2 dates which will result in a date formated string, what you need to do is to get the difference in hours of both dates, to do that, you need the duration method:

```
let start = moment("2018-07-27T14:56:33.763Z");
let end = moment("2018-07-28T13:56:33.763Z");
let diff = end.diff(start);

let diffData = moment.duration(diff);
alert((diffData.days() * 24) + diffData.hours());
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```js
var units = ["year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute", "second", "millisecond"];
var unitmapping = {month:12,day:30,hour:24,minute:60,second:60,millisecond:1000};

function getDiff(start, end)
{
  var duration = "", start = moment(start), end = moment(end);
  units.forEach(function(unit,index){
    var diff = Math.abs(end.diff(start,unit));
    if(unitmapping[unit]) diff = (diff%unitmapping[unit]).toFixed(0);
    duration += diff + " " 
                + unit
                + (diff==1 ? "":"s")
                + (index!=units.length-1 ? " : ":"");
  });
  return duration;
}

console.log(getDiff("2018-07-27T14:56:33.843Z","2018-07-27T14:56:33.763Z"));
console.log(getDiff("2018-07-26T14:56:33.843Z","2018-07-27T14:56:33.763Z"));
console.log(getDiff("2018-07-27T14:46:33.843Z","2018-07-27T14:56:33.763Z"));
console.log(getDiff("2018-07-27T14:56:33.843Z","2048-07-29T14:56:33.763Z"));
console.log(getDiff("2018-09-27T14:56:33.843Z","2048-07-29T14:56:33.763Z"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```