# Calculate difference between 2 dates in ISO format in JavaScript/TS

Tags: javascript

I have 2 dates in ISO format like so:

```
startDate: "2018-09-14T00:20:12.200Z"
endDate: "2018-09-16T00:18:00.000Z"
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate the difference between those 2 days. So with the given dates it would be 1 Day, 21 Hours, 47 Minutes and 40 Seconds (pardon me if the subtraction is not correct).

Tried to do using the following:

```
const start = new Date(startDate).getTime();
const end = new Date(endDate).getTime();
return Math.abs(end - start).toString();
```

However this doesn't seem to work.

Any clues?

Comment: If you subtract the dates (without getTime) you get the difference. However, its it milisecondsI think. You are better off using momentjs or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works. Things to note:

1. `getTime()` is not needed as the `new Date()` constructor returns the time in milliseconds.
2. The date should always be in RFC2822 or ISO formats, else it becomes useless across various browsers, even while using `moment.js`.

If you can use `moment.js`, [Get time difference using moment.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51600403/4593057)

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51388623/4593057) to know why only the standardized formats need to be used.

```js
var unitmapping = {"days":24*60*60*1000,
                   "hours":60*60*1000,
                   "minutes":60*1000,
                   "seconds":1000};

function floor(value)
{
    return Math.floor(value)
}

function getHumanizedDiff(diff)
{
    return floor(diff/unitmapping.days)+" days "+
           floor((diff%unitmapping.days)/unitmapping.hours)+" hours "+
           floor((diff%unitmapping.hours)/unitmapping.minutes)+" minutes "+
           floor((diff%unitmapping.minutes)/unitmapping.seconds)+" seconds "+
           floor((diff%unitmapping.seconds))+" milliseconds";
}

console.log(getHumanizedDiff(new Date("2018-09-16T00:18:00.000Z") - new Date("2018-09-14T00:20:12.200Z")));
console.log(getHumanizedDiff(new Date("2018-09-16T00:18:00.000Z") - new Date("2018-09-04T00:20:02.630Z")));
console.log(getHumanizedDiff(new Date("2018-09-17T00:16:04.000Z") - new Date("2018-09-14T00:20:12.240Z")));
```

Comment: That's a really helpful answer. Saved me some work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

yBrodsky's suggestion to use moment.js is probably the best idea, but if you're curious how to do the math here, it would go something like this:

```
const start = new Date(startDate).getTime();
const end = new Date(endDate).getTime();
let seconds = Math.round(Math.abs(end - start) / 1000); // We'll round away millisecond differences.
const days = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
seconds -= days * 86400;
const hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
seconds -= hours * 3600;
minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
seconds -= minutes * 60;
```

This leaves you with `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` as numbers that you can format into a string result however you like.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var startDate =  "2018-09-14T00:20:12.200Z"
var endDate = "2018-09-16T00:18:00.000Z"

const start = new Date(startDate).getTime();
const end = new Date(endDate).getTime();
const milliseconds = Math.abs(end - start).toString()
const seconds = parseInt(milliseconds / 1000);
const minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60);
const hours = parseInt(minutes / 60);
const days = parseInt(hours / 24);
const time = days + ":" + hours % 24 + ":" + minutes % 60 + ":" + seconds % 60;
console.log(time)
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert the milliseconds to string ? And again parse it back to  integer ?